# Which Fisher information to use to obtain Cramer-Rao bound in expectation-maximization?

Tags: expectation-maximization, fisher-information, cramer-rao

I have a rather limited understanding of statistical estimation theory so I apologize if my question is strange or trivial.

Say I have an expectation-maximization-based algorithm for determining the parameters $\boldsymbol{\theta}$. Let $\mathbf{y}$ denote the incomplete data and $\mathbf{x}$ the complete data. I wish to determine the theoretical lower bound of $\boldsymbol{\theta}$'s variance, and I understand that this is done using the Cramer-Rao Lower Bound (CRLB), defined as (for an unbiased estimator, as in my case):

$$\operatorname{CRLB} = E\left[\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \boldsymbol{\theta}}\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \boldsymbol{\theta}^\top}\right] = \mathcal{I}(\boldsymbol{\theta})^{-1}$$

My question is this: Does the log-likelihood function $\ell(\boldsymbol{\theta})$ correspond to the complete data, $\mathbf{x}$, or the incomplete data, $\mathbf{y}$? In other words, do I calculate the CRLB from the complete data Fisher information matrix, or the incomplete data one? What's the rationale behind the answer?

Comment: If you had to choose between the complete and incomplete data, which would you pick and why? It helps to know your initial reasoning before providing an answer.

Comment: @mhdadk I'm leaning towards the incomplete data log-likelihood since that's the one we maximize in order to obtain the ML estimates. On the other hand, in the M-step we are maximizing the conditional expectation of the complete data log-likelihood. I don't know how to proceed from here.